# Segmentation fault with strcmp

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file and break each line into parts and when I try to do strcmp or strncmp I incur a segmentation fault. Can anyone please help me with it?

```
char *input_file = argv[1];
char *line;
char *type = NULL;
ifstream infile;
infile.open(input_file, ifstream::in);
while(!infile.eof())
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(infile, s);
    line = new char[s.length()+1];
    strcpy(line, s.c_str());
    type = strtok(line,"(");
    cout<<"type"<<type<<"\n";
    if(s.size()>0)
        s.resize(s.size()-1);
    if(s[0]=='#')
        continue;
    if(!strncmp(type,"INPUT",5))
```

Comment: What is the output up to the `strncmp`?

Comment: Just to let you know, segmentation fault occurs when you are trying to access memory illegally, like using a pointer for an array without allocating space for the array first.

Comment: [`while !eof` is almost always wrong.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5) In which book is this mistake found?

Comment: you aren't deallocating the `line` buffer. It's a bug but it's only a memory leak. No crash here.

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause a segfault in this snippet. There's more though, obviously (it ends with an `if` with no body), which is where it's probably occurring.

Comment: only when I use the strcmp i get a seg fault.. i tried comparing it as type=="INPUT".. then there is no seg fault but output is wrong

Comment: `type=="INPUT"` does a comparison of the *pointers*, not the values.  And since `"INPUT"` is almost certainly part of the program's data section and `type` is just pointing to some block of dynamically allocated memory, the two pointers should never be equal.

Comment: `if (std::string(type) == "INPUT")` might work, if you can guarantee that `type` will never be null (and don't care that it might just *start with* "INPUT", rather than being *equal* to "INPUT").  But if you could, you probably wouldn't have asked your question...

Answer (score 5):

This might be a lot easier with strings (and streams), and certainly more "C++":

```
std::string line;

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
  // process "line", e.g. by tokenizing:
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  std::string token;
  while (iss >> token)
  {
    // process token, e.g. use token.substr(...)
  }

  // or directly, as a whole:
  std::cout << line.substr(line.find_first_of('(') + 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: All well and good when the delimiter is whitespace.  Needs clarification on how this would work with "(" as a delimiter, though, as is the case in the OP's example.

Comment: @cHao: That's true, but I think the OP isn't actually trying to tokenize by `(`, but rather she's just trying to find the first occurrence. I'll update the post, though, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A few issues:

1. You are not checking the return value of `strtok` for NULL. This can result in a segmentation fault when you pass this value into `strncmp`.
2. You are accessing `s[0]` when `s` may be an empty string.
3. As Tomalak Geret'kal said in a comment above, don't use `while(!infile.eof())`. Use `while(std::getline(infile, s))` instead. Even if `eof()` returned false, reading from the stream may fail.

Comment: i checked output of strtok.. it return INPUT as the value and seems to work fine

Comment: @Chin: Are you sure it didn't return NULL for any of the lines in the file?

Comment: ya am sure.. I printed out all the lines and checked

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason to use the C-style string functions here at all. Trying to stick to roughly the same names to keep the intent apparent, I'd do something like this:

```
std::string s, type;

while (std::getline(infile,s)) {
    int paren = s.find('(');
    if (paren != std::string::npos)
        type = std::string(s, 0, paren);
    std::cout << "type" << type << "\n";
    if (s[0] == '#')
        continue;
    if (std::string(s, 0, 5) == "INPUT")
         // presumably more here...
```

Depending on what you're really trying to accomplish, there's a good chance that this can be improved still further. My immediate reaction would be to do something like:

```
// There's probably a better name for this, but I don't know what.
struct line {
    std::string type;
    std::string tail;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) { 
        std::getline(is, l.type, '(');
        std::getline(is, l.tail);
        if (l.tail.size() > 0)    // There's probably room for improvement here.
            l.tail.resize(l.tail.size()-1);
        return is;
    }
};
```

You'd then use this something like:

```
line x;

while (infile >> x) {
    std::cout << "type" << x.type << "\n";
    if (std::string(x.type, 0, 5) == "INPUT")
        // whatever
```

If you're always looking at the first five characters (or up to some delimiter, etc.) of the input as some sort of command (or whatever), you could have the `line` class parse that out separately as well.